# Knockout options binding reference property

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, properties

I´m having an observableArray, that gets populated by an ajax call and looking like

```
appModel.foo().bar().fooBarCategories()
[
Object:
  id: Object
     type: "integer"
     value: "4986517"
  name: "Adwords"
, 
Object
, 
Object,
...
]
```

and I´m having a select where I want the optionsText to be "name" property and the value "id.value" property

like:

```
<select id="fooBarCategory" 
  data-bind="
      options: appModel.foo().bar().fooBarCategories(), 
      optionsText: name, 
      value: id.value"
></select>
```

but it doesn't work saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function
>   (){return id.value }" Message: id is not defined

so how would can I achieve that? tried stuff like `value:$data.id.value` or

```
value:this.id.value
```

this is how I got it to work with the name property:

```
optionsText:function(item) {
    return item.name
}
```

but if do similiar with the id property

```
value:function(item){ return item.id.value }
```

then the value attr in the generated options keeps blank

here you have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q65nz/1/

Comment: see the updated answer. Note `optionsValue` instead of `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i will suggest do it like this
create a function because it is an object so wont take the usuall form.

```
self.setValue = function (item) {
    return item.id.value
}
```

And now call it like this

```
<select data-bind="
    options: appModel.foo().bar().fooBarCategories(), 
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue : setValue
">
</select>
```

### Fiddle Demo

### Fiddle Demo with Your Provided Data

You should use `optionsValue` binding instead of `value` binding

Comment: hey thanks a lot ! , could you adjust it so my fiddle works ? you will see the difference in the id object thats an object itself http://jsfiddle.net/q65nz/1/

Comment: No problem. I found this solution for the first time myself. Hahaha. Never knew that it could be done like that. Just tried and it worked. Then shared...